# How to update image in UWP StorageItemThumbnail (file)

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10, windows-10-universal

I'm trying to write a rutine that'll update the thumbnail image inside an MP3 og M4A file using C# inside a UWP app.

I may be looking in the wrong place, but I can't seem to locate a method on the StorageItemThumbnail  or StorageItem classes.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks,
Bjarne

Comment: can you please clarify your question? at the moment it is really unclear what you are asking. thanks!

Comment: Certainly. I am writing a program to update the album of the users music library. I'm using the  StorageItem and StoreageItemThumbnail classes to determine the size of the thumbnail in the MP3 and M4A files in the users collection as well as display the thumbnail item. What I need to figure out is how to update the thumbnail image inside the music files with a higher resolution thumbnail image. Although the above classes have read methods that allow me to query for the thumbnail properties and retrieve it, I have failed to find a method that allows me to update thumbnail to the file.

Comment: Currently, as far as I known there is no API for us to update the original thumbnail image inside the music file.
I will recommend you submit your feedback and suggestion about this requirement on this UserVoice forum (https://wpdev.uservoice.com/) to Microsoft.